# .htaccess how convert this URL in friendly?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

any question community

how convert this URL in friendly ?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^/2/1281-home/Breakin-Em-In-7.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p//2/2-1281-home.jpg [L]
```

i try . . .. but not work

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/?$4//?$4-$1-$2.jpg [L]
```

help me please !!!

See the image of the database ---->

http://s13.postimg.org/63mrxn3if/IDPRODUCT.jpg

my .htaccess --->

RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
    RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/presta1_5/]
    RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

```
# Images

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/presta1_5/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]


</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /presta1_5/index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Comment: Where do those "2"'s come from in your rule's target?

Comment: "2" is id_product in databse

Comment: See the images --> http://s13.postimg.org/63mrxn3if/IDPRODUCT.jpg

Comment: What are you trying to do and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want to build the rule of URL-friendly, the images do not show: (

Answer (score 0):

why there is two slash?  RewriteRule ^1281-home/Breakin-Em-In-7.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/**/**2/2-1281-home.jpg [L]

Answer (score 0):

READY !!! SOLVE !!

BY THE post -->http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/155511-solved-htaccess-and-my-images-folder/

Dont use a rewrite for images. You need to set the path correctly in the img src element. if your images folder is under the root
< img src="/images/image.jpg" />

not
< img src="images/image.jpg" />